# Can enter do something on tag selection?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I *really* like the improved tag selection (autocomplete) engine.

The only thing I don't like is *pressing enter* doesn't do anything, unless you press down arrow first (to select the closest match).

Comment: What exactly do you suggest that enter *do*?

Comment: @GraceNote: what about submit?

Comment: I think selecting the closest match would be good